# Change projectile trajectory in unreal engine 4 to behave like a wave

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-development-kit

I am new to unreal engine , 
I am trying to change my projectile trajectory so that my bullet move like a wave. Is this something that I can accomplish using unreal block editor or do I need to write some C/C++ code?
I have done this using the block editor

[image]

But the projectile is spawn and the drop on the floor and keep oscillating.
Can somebody tell me at least if I on the right way or if I have to write some c code to manage this.

PS : game is a 2D game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable gravity in your Projectile. To do this select ProjectileMovement in your Actor and change the ProjectileGravityScale property to 0.0